# In Snowflake, how do I include a timestamp in a result that has zero rows?

Tags: timestamp, snowflake

I have run a query in Snowflake that returns zero rows. How do I add a timestamp to a query that returns zero rows?

Comment: Can you show the query you're running, and what expected results are when there are zero rows? Is it okay to return an additional row in the case where there is a result set?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but:

```
SELECT *
FROM ( VALUES (<your_timestamp>) ) AS t(ts)
LEFT JOIN ( <your query> ) AS q
    ON 1=1
```

If "your query" return zero rows you will get a null for each column in that query together with the timestamp.

Example for postgres: [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vDpCnAUc)

Comment: This was very helpful. I assume switching the order won't change the results. I seem to get the same result for the query as a stand-alone.

    SELECT *  
    FROM (My query) AS q  
    LEFT JOIN  
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS Time_of_Query) AS t

Comment: If you want to change the order, use a `RIGHT JOIN` . I updated the fiddle above as a demonstration